# How do I replace a variable value with a another value, character and numeric?

Tags: sas

I am trying to replace specific variable values with either a character, or numeric, value on a case by case basis.

My code for changing to value of "no" to "NULL" is as follows:

```
DATA tp_01_pa_remove_no;
  SET tp_01_pa_renamed;
  IF variable_name="no" THEN "NULL";
RUN;
```

I also want to replace additional values:

```
DATA tp_01_pa_remove_nulls;
SET tp_01_pa_renamed;
IF PAFB_OTHERACTIV_4A1="no" OR "none" OR "None" OR "N/A" THEN PAFB_OTHERACTIV_4A1="NULL";
```

RUN;

Answer (score 0):

To rename a variable whose value is exactly `no`, you would do the following:

```
data tp_01_pa_remove_no;
    set tp_01_pa_renamed;

    if(variable_Name = "no") then variable_name = "NULL";
run;
```

This is assuming that `variable_name` has at least a length of 4.

Comment: Great. Thanks! What if I wanted to make changes in other variables? DATA     tp_01_pa_remove_nulls;
       SET tp_01_pa_renamed;
 IF variable_name="NULL" THEN variable_name_2=0 AND variable_name_3=0;
    RUN;

Comment: @jcorroon This is a basic enough issue I think you need to read some beginning SAS books/documentation or even just the SAS documentation.    Programming is something you're going to have a real hard time with otherwise if you don't know how to do conditional statements or DO/ENDs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you're used to Excel, there are IFN and IFC, which are excel-style statements.  First argument is the 'if' condition, second is returned 'if true', third is returned 'if false', and optional fourth is 'if missing/null' (which normally doesn't happen).

```
data want;
  set have;
  variable_name = ifc(variable_name='no','NULL',variable_name);
run;
```

IFN of course returns a numeric.  (Neither statement cares what type the first argument is, by the way.)